# How to display all number by increment?

Tags: validation, for-loop, input, increment

i was task to ask a user to enter a number in range from 1 to 15 and after 5 input, i suppose to display all the number that enter by the user. 
    saying the user enter 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, this is what i suppose to display:
    1 2
    1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5 6

```
package barChartPrinting;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class barChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int getNumber;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++){

            System.out.println("Enter a numbers in range of 1 to 15: ");
            getNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (getNumber < 1 || getNumber > 15){
                System.out.println("Invalid number!, please re-enter: ");
                getNumber = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            }


        }

    //end of statement here 
    }

}
```

Comment: lol, the display number all mix up. it just suppose to display a number in order.

Comment: I don't see where you display any number, you assign values to getNumber but you never print anything unless the user enters a bad number.

Comment: isn't that the point? i ask how to display them.

Comment: you said in your comment "the display number all mix up" which made me think you had tried and  had not seen what you expected. If you showed me your attempt I would help you fix it.